# Is it possible to run / serialize Dataflow job without having all dependencies locally?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have created a pipeline for Google Cloud Dataflow using Apache Beam, but I cannot have Python dependencies locally. However, there are no problems for those dependencies to be installed remotely.

Is it somehow possible to run the job or create a template without executing Python code in my local (development) environment?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/samples/molecules-walkthrough#run_the_preprocessing_pipeline). Basically, you write the python pipeline, then deploy it via command line with

```
python your_pipeline.py \
--project $YOUR_GCP_PROJECT \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--temp_location $WORK_DIR/beam-temp \
--setup_file ./setup.py \
--work-dir $WORK_DIR
```

The crucial part is **`--runner DataflowRunner`**, so it uses Google Dataflow (and not your local installation) to run the pipeline. Obviously, you have to set your Google account and credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yeah, of course, I know, I have set up everything, but somehow even with the DataflowRunner, my application is still being executed locally before it has been deployed to GCS.

Comment: Have you tried to move your code on Google Storage, then execute the above command with the Google Cloud Shell? You will have to change the file paths to `gs://your-bucket/whatever.py` In that case, I don't think it will use your local environment at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not 100% sure that this is possible, but you may:

- Define a `requirements.txt` file with all of the dependencies for pipeline execution
- Avoid importing and using your dependencies in pipeline-construction time, only in execution time code.

So, for instance, your file may look like this:

```
import apache_beam as beam

with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  result = (p | ReadSomeData(...)
            | beam.ParDo(MyForbiddenDependencyDoFn()))
```

And in the same file, your DoFn would be importing your dependency from within the pipeline execution-time code, so the `process` method, for instance. See:

```
class MyForbiddenDependencyDoFn(beam.DoFn):

  def process(self, element):
    import forbidden_dependency as fd
    yield fd.totally_cool_operation(element)
```

When you execute your pipeline, you can do:

```
python your_pipeline.py \
    --project $GCP_PROJECT \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --temp_location $GCS_LOCATION/temp \
    --requirements_file=requirements.txt
```

I have never tried this, but it just may work : )